# Illustrator not find font (glyphs) inside SVG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, font-design, glyphs

I make some work in Illustrator and save it as an SVG.
Configurations are:

[image: SVG save configuration]

As you see, I used Fonts SVG and subsettings used glyphs.
Now my code look like:

[image: Inside SVG]

Now I want to change font name to custom and change glyphs inside SVG code
I changed font name and glyphs and saved it, because I thought Illustrator read fonts inside my saved SVG file.

[image]

But no. When I try to open the file again with illustrator, it gives an error font not found.

Now:

**HOW TO OPEN INSIDE SVG GLYPHS AS A FONT ON ILLUSTRATOR? IS IT POSSIBLE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe applications do not open fonts from files. Its not that they could not but dont. So if you dont have a font with that name once you open it in illustrator for editing its now gone.

Reason appears to be that adobe is one of the big seller of fonts and commercial fonts usually allow embedding but not opening for re edit.

What you are asking is not possible in any adobe application.

Comment: thank you very much. probably I will create a font and call it from illustrator.